# Github Pages return GET 404 by wrong path

Tags: html, reactjs, github-pages

I'm deploying a website built with React on Github Pages. I've set my package.json with

```
"homepage": https://stdev17.github.io/arenatime
```

But unlikely in local, I've got 404 error with unrelated path like this.

GET 404 errors with images:

[image]

And my site has gone completely white. I'm referencing images like

```
<img
  alt=""
  src="/github-logo.svg"
  width="34"
  height="34"
  className="github"
/>
```

Is there any rescue for it?

Comment: This is not the proper way to display an image in React. You should first import the image like this `import image from 'imagePath/image.svg;'` and then use the import varaible like this: `<img src={image} .../>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know your projectstructure but did you already tried

```
<img
  alt=""
  src="./github-logo.svg"
  width="34"
  height="34"
  className="github"
/>
```

or

```
<img
  alt=""
  src="/arenatime/github-logo.svg"
  width="34"
  height="34"
  className="github"
/>
```

?

I think the second solution should work.

Comment: I've set the path like your solution, and copied all the images from /public folder to its subfolder. I think it's kinda HACK, but it works anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these files **aren't** there.

Just by accessing https://stdev17.github.io/arenatime and reading the console, you'll find:

[image: missing files]

So I suggest you to double-check for that files on *github.io* **AND** if they are inside the root folder.

Comment: My repository is 'arenatime' but not 'stdev17.github.io.' I'll check this solution soon.